# Python Enum, when and where to use?

Tags: python, enums, python-3.4

Python 3.4.0 introduced `enum`, I've read the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) but still don't know the usage of it. From my perspective, `enum.Enum` is an extended `namedtuple` type, which may not be true. So these are what I want to know about `Enum`:

1. When and where to use `Enum`?
2. Why do we need `Enum`? What are the advantages?
3. What exactly is an `Enum`?

Comment: Another excellent answer is:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37601645/208880

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this meta says I should: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429367/closing-consistency

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> 1. When and where to use enums?

- When you have a variable that takes one of a limited set of possible values.

For example, the days of the week:

```
class Weekday(Enum):
    MONDAY = 1
    TUESDAY = 2
    WEDNESDAY = 3
    THURSDAY = 4
    FRIDAY = 5
    SATURDAY = 6
    SUNDAY = 7
```

> 2. Why do we need enum?  What are the advantages?

- Enums are advantageous because they give a name to a constant, which makes code more readable; and because the individual members cannot be rebound, making Python Enums semi-constant (because the `Enum` itself could still be rebound).
- Besides more readable code, debugging is also easier as you see a name along with the value, not just the value
- Desired behavior can be added to Enums

For example, as anyone who has worked with the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module knows, `datetime` and `date` have two different representations for the days of the week: 0-6 or 1-7.  Rather than keep track of that ourselves we can add a method to the `Weekday` enum to extract the day from the `datetime` or `date` instance and return the matching enum member:

```
    @classmethod
    def from_date(cls, date):
        return cls(date.isoweekday())
```

> 3. What exactly is Enum?

- Enum is a [type](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type), whose members are named constants, that all belong to (or should) a logical group of values.  So far I have created `Enum`s for:

  ```
  - the days of the week
  - the months of the year
  - US Federal Holidays in a year
  ```

`FederalHoliday` is my most complex; it uses [this recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19330461/208880), and has methods to return the actual date the holiday takes place on for the year given, the next business day if the day in question is a holiday (or the range of days skipped includes the holiday or weekends), and the complete set of dates for a year.  Here it is:

```
class FederalHoliday(AutoEnum):
    NewYear = "First day of the year.", 'absolute', Month.JANUARY, 1
    MartinLutherKingJr = "Birth of Civil Rights leader.", 'relative', Month.JANUARY, Weekday.MONDAY, 3
    President = "Birth of George Washington", 'relative', Month.FEBRUARY, Weekday.MONDAY, 3
    Memorial = "Memory of fallen soldiers", 'relative', Month.MAY, Weekday.MONDAY, 5
    Independence = "Declaration of Independence", 'absolute', Month.JULY, 4
    Labor = "American Labor Movement", 'relative', Month.SEPTEMBER, Weekday.MONDAY, 1
    Columbus = "Americas discovered", 'relative', Month.OCTOBER, Weekday.MONDAY, 2
    Veterans = "Recognition of Armed Forces service", 'relative', Month.NOVEMBER, 11, 1
    Thanksgiving = "Day of Thanks", 'relative', Month.NOVEMBER, Weekday.THURSDAY, 4
    Christmas = "Birth of Jesus Christ", 'absolute', Month.DECEMBER, 25

    def __init__(self, doc, type, month, day, occurrence=None):
        self.__doc__ = doc
        self.type = type
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
        self.occurrence = occurrence

    def date(self, year):
        "returns the observed date of the holiday for `year`"
        if self.type == 'absolute' or isinstance(self.day, int):
            holiday =  Date(year, self.month, self.day)
            if Weekday(holiday.isoweekday()) is Weekday.SUNDAY:
                holiday = holiday.replace(delta_day=1)
            return holiday
        days_in_month = days_per_month(year)
        target_end = self.occurrence * 7 + 1
        if target_end > days_in_month[self.month]:
            target_end = days_in_month[self.month]
        target_start = target_end - 7
        target_week = list(xrange(start=Date(year, self.month, target_start), step=one_day, count=7))
        for holiday in target_week:
            if Weekday(holiday.isoweekday()) is self.day:
                return holiday

    @classmethod
    def next_business_day(cls, date, days=1):
        """
        Return the next `days` business day from date.
        """
        holidays = cls.year(date.year)
        years = set([date.year])
        while days > 0:
            date = date.replace(delta_day=1)
            if date.year not in years:
                holidays.extend(cls.year(date.year))
                years.add(date.year)
            if Weekday(date.isoweekday()) in (Weekday.SATURDAY, Weekday.SUNDAY) or date in holidays:
                continue
            days -= 1
        return date

    @classmethod
    def year(cls, year):
        """
        Return a list of the actual FederalHoliday dates for `year`.
        """
        holidays = []
        for fh in cls:
            holidays.append(fh.date(year))
        return holidays
```

---

**Notes**:

- `Date` is from [my dbf package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf)
- the enhanced `xrange` (supporting a range of dates) is also custom, but I don't think I have included it anywhere; I'll stuff it in my `dbf` package next time I tinker with it.
- Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.