# TypeScript: why is exact enum type not enforced?

Tags: typescript

Please have a look at this simple code:

```
const enum MyEnum {
    Zero
} 

const foo: MyEnum.Zero = 0 // OK as expected (since MyEnum.Zero is zero)
const bar: MyEnum.Zero = 1 // OK, but expected Error! Why?
```

How can I enforce exact, narrow number type, i.e. `0` in this case?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgWQJ4FEmoN4BQMxMAWnAE4gEC+MBBoksAZiCAFzra4B05VGAF4YABhgB6CTADyAaxgBDCPAAeABzjAocACYwAFBACWYYHG44U-SiBjGVAL1sBKRuGgwARoopdMVsg2giIAjJLSUrIA0gA03oiwcBpaOvpYFFQUAIQwAOoAFhgA-EA)

UPD: enums seem to be broken https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11559

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question... numeric enums are also used as bit flags, and there is no way to ask for a "non-flag" numeric enum.  You can make your own enum-like object which is stricter, but it's [verbose](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBZAngUWAVzEg3gLABQSSEAHjAPYBOALkvNcFIwFoS3VIC8SABgDcJMpRoMk9NDGSdufKTIjUAZknnURxUeSp1GzVowDywZPwCM2sfsnTZSMxaWy1T89t3iDTFmyQAFQB3Hn4AJhs9CUYHZBCw1xV1BO0AXxI41EwcPH4493QsXABtAGsINHcC9SLcgF0vYiMA1WpqAC5s4rAAOk1FASQAemGkajKQNBIWxgAjEFouutx+rkTLEbGubloAQhISIA).  Do you want me to elaborate?

Comment: @jcalz Well if it's not hard for you.. But mostly I've decided to go with verbose types like you said

Comment: @jcalz that verbose enum works like magic BTW. I am appreciating it more and more as I work with it.. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not really mentioned in [the `enum` section of the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums), but all `number` values are assignable to any numeric enum type.  Another draft of a TypeScript handbook says [the following](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-New-Handbook/blob/1ba33481f0a1469b4ccfe12ddb255380d1ccdde9/reference/Assignability.md#simple-types):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#enums

> A few of the [assignability] rules are odd because of historical restrictions. For example, any number is assignable to a numeric enum, but this is not true for string enums. Only strings that are known to be part of a string enum are assignable to it. That's because numeric enums existed before union types and literal types, so their rules were originally looser.

And currently it is mentioned in [a section on type compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums) that numeric enums and `number` are mutually assignable.

Numeric enums in TypeScript have historically been used to support [bit fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field), using bit masking and bitwise operations to combine explicitly declared enum values to get new ones:

```
enum Color {
  Red = 0xFF0000,
  Green = 0x00FF00,
  Blue = 0x0000FF
}
const yellow: Color = Color.Red | Color.Green; // 0xFFFF00
const white: Color = Color.Red | Color.Green | Color.Blue; // 0xFFFFFF
const blue: Color = white & ~yellow; // 0x0000FF
```

And because this use of enums exists in real-world code, it would be a breaking change to alter this behavior ([see comment on microsoft/TypeScript#8020](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8020#issuecomment-208717449)).  And the maintainers of the language don't seem particularly inclined to try (see [microsoft/TypeScript#22311](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22311)).

So, for better or for worse, numeric enums are loosely typed to be mostly synonymous with `number`.

---

It is possible to roll your own stricter enum-like object, but it involves doing by hand a number of the things that happen automatically when you use the `enum` syntax.  Here's one possible implementation (which doesn't give you a [reverse mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings)):

```
namespace MyEnum {
  export const Zero = 0;
  export type Zero = typeof Zero;

  export const One = 1;
  export type One = typeof One;

  export const Two = 2;
  export type Two = typeof Two;
}
type MyEnum = typeof MyEnum[keyof typeof MyEnum];

const foo: MyEnum.Zero = 0 // okay
const bar: MyEnum.Zero = 1 // error!
```

This works as follows... when you write `enum X { Y = 123, Z = 456 }`, TypeScript introduces a value at runtime named `X`, with properties `X.Y` and `X.Z`.  It also introduces *types* named `X`, `X.Y`, and `X.Z`.  The types `X.Y` and `X.Z` are just the types of the values `X.Y` and `X.Z`.  But the type `X` is not the type of the value `X`.  Instead, it is the union of the property types `X.Y | X.Z`.

I used `namespace`, `export`, `const`, and `type` above to achieve a similar effect. But the difference here is that the assignability rule for numeric enums doesn't apply, so you get the strict type checking you expect.

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwLACgpQErAAmUAvFAAwAeAYtefeQDTa4DiywopFl9t9zHFABCCMMG5UG5WtgC+2AMZwQAZwAuUAJ7AESAO4AuWIhTd4SZADoCxAD4nLV9pxABuKAHpPPWv3JKKhpQ+gAWAJbqwMYWZmSx1rZQDgnOHFwpptai4h7evn6yWMpqmgBGYtGOcSERUVAAZFAAfjp6cPp5PlIMRdj9WCAAhhDAqgAOQ4oSALJaAKLg0JhCwJTjKJolwQBawMhwkm4sUGsbyJrqWuMSewfcVzdwAGZQd3DHWCdnm1DbmgB5EASMgARk+uB+FygjwkQJBMOuwBeUHhn2+61+-ygABV9IcyAAmCGnTHQ2G4-EPJEovEfeTYClzRaQalPV7MpYAbQA1sAtCjYSjOZAALro4pBTTPOBwYwiiBWd6SLw+OA8oZaQKlKBlIbIeULJZK-YEqCg1WnZAHZAAQgGQA)

Comment: Great answer as always, but shouldn't it look more like `export const Zero = 0 as const;` because currently `MyEnum.Zero` when used as *value* has type `number` instead of `0`? In my case this matters, maybe other cases will not be influenced by this..

Comment: `const z = 0` should infer a type of `0` for `z`, not `number`.  That is, there's no difference between `const z = 0` and `const z = 0 as const`.  Can you demonstrate the issue you're describing?  I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Well I lost the case, sorry, but it was related to the fact that `foo` in `let foo = MyEnum.Zero` will be `0` and `number` with and without `as const` respectively.. But, `let` variable should be `number` anyway, so... Okay, ignore my comment, I think it's pointless (sorry)

Answer (score 1):

As @jcalz has mentioned, Typescript doesn't differentiate between `number` and `MyEnum.X` in the case of a Numeric Enum:

> any number is assignable to a numeric enum, but this is not true for string enums

And that's sad...

It basically means that you cannot rely on the "type" of `MyEnum.Zero` by itself at all.  So you have two choices:

### Suboptimal Solution 1) Use a mutated version of the type

```
enum MyEnum {
    three = 3,
    four,
    five,
}

type EnumKeysToTrue = { [ P in MyEnum]: true }; // { 3: true; 4: true; 5: true; }
type TrueObject<T extends MyEnum> = Pick<EnumKeysToTrue, T>;

const a0: TrueObject<MyEnum.three> = { 3: true }; // OK, as expected
const a1: TrueObject<MyEnum.three> = { 4: true }; // Error
const a2: TrueObject<3> = { [MyEnum.three]: true }; // OK, as expected, just in case
const a3: TrueObject<4> = { [MyEnum.three]: true }; // Error, as expected, just in case
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gWAFAEgAuALAJ2GCgF4oBmAGkywDMB7MAm7OgSwDdhWBfTTDjgAHEkkgBpYHADOAFQZyCYEuRRQA2lAAKUdiFiJkAXQBcUHMpK8A3FAD09qOornLKuwBY3VuwFYfDyh+DCFRKCUVAHkAIwArYABjHAAeOShgAA8cUAATGUNxCAA+Mh12RIBrFKKpWQVIngjimwEMRIYQGRwoAEMABnNG2ITklPgigDp8ImBStUpA6ztHKCiJKj6CrNFk4FzMDq6e3oBGIasRpNSJ5GnCYnnnKG8LK2CVpwQCAgYCQ863T6ACYLtF4tcUhQnuoNLdIPdZmY3ioPg4nOtNr1tpldjlcps4mAgfooIlscAAcc+q4IpcIWNPDDNPCIIjiMj3Mt0VBvr8WFsMrjrvtCcSeqTyTJgEA)

Here we are actually storing an object with its single key being the enum value that we want and its value being `true`.

It might not be ideal, as getting the value out of these `a{x}` variables via `Object.keys(a1)[0]` might not be preferred; yet, it can work in certain cases.

---

### Suboptimal Solution 2) Use the value of the enum and the type of the RHS of the assignment!

```
enum MyEnum {
    three = 3,
    four,
    five,
}

type EnumKeysToTrue = { [ P in MyEnum]: true }; // { 3: true; 4: true; 5: true; }
type Enumified<T extends number> = EnumKeysToTrue[T] extends true ? T : never;

const v0: Enumified<MyEnum.three> = MyEnum.four; // Error: Type 'MyEnum.four' is not assignable to type 'MyEnum.three'.ts(2322)
const v1: Enumified<MyEnum.three> = 4;  // Unfortunately, OK. So don't use it this way!
const v2: Enumified<4> = MyEnum.three;  // Type 'MyEnum.three' is not assignable to type '4'
const v3: Enumified<9> = 9;             // error: type 9 is not assignable to never
const v4: Enumified<4> = MyEnum.four;   // OK, as expected :)
let num: number = 9;
const v5: Enumified<typeof num> = MyEnum.four;  // Type 'MyEnum.four' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAsgngUXNA3gWAFAEgAuALAJ2GCgF4oBmAGkywDMB7MAm7OgSwDdhWBfTTDjgAHEkkgBpYHADOAFQZyCYEuRRQA2lAAKUdiFiJkAXQBcUHMpK8A3FAD09qOornLKuwBY3VuwFYfDyh+DCFRKHEIdg5gABMAHjkoYAAPHFBYmShkACNgAgA+MgjkKVkFJRUNOWNktIys9xIAfigk8xBgbgIbAQwAYwYQGRwoTgAGc0jo9jj4+EiAOnwiYCLyBeRFxmY7RwiCAgYCczkREgByTchtpgILvSyQBlGAQxkZdgBzEFecgBsSDgGBZzlArkYbitiBdljIABQAJgoiMRAEpMINhqNOABGKbIGZza4QZaEYjrKCeOxYfYAVRAjAIODAv3S-zgVCgAHkJIsoABlEGxIYXUZgGQkdijfDsLIAd1ecAAhJihiMxoiCZAiQlPJSSWTVjT9mdwhCltDgA85dkXlB3p8fn9ARYQWFLp4LmrsWNXCUdTEEgBOSnBmlYWlOfJHE6g8LBx52t4fb6-AFAkGdbo+jWcbwBqJB+L64qGnY9KBRnkSLnvOqifrpWJQUwYjCA0bIDqQPIEYrh3M4gKF3XxD0MOjZSAGyGkismpxmy7lu42p72x1pl2Z+OXbP5WE4BHI1FooA)

This one might work much better, since once can take the values of `v{x}` variables and go from there!  **Just be careful that the assigned value must be passed to `Enumified<>` and the Enum must be on the RHS of the assignment**, otherwise, like `v1` above, it's going to work inadvertently.

---

PS. You cannot generalize `EnumKEyToTrue` for all the enums in your codebase.  It needs to be one per enum instance.