# Restrict possible values for function parameter

Tags: typescript

```
class Coordinate {
  constructor(readonly x: number, readonly y: number) {}
}

const Up = new Coordinate(0, -1);
const Right = new Coordinate(1, 0);
const Down = new Coordinate(0, 1);
const Left = new Coordinate(-1, 0);

// I would like direction to be Up or Right or Down or Left
function move(direction: Coordinate) {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to force the `direction` parameter to be one of `Up`, `Right`, `Down`, `Left` ?

Comment: What is `Coordinate`?  Please provide a [mre].

Comment: it's just a class with `x` and `y` properties

Comment: Well, you can't restrict the input to be particular *values*.  You can restrict to be particular *types*, and you can make the type of `Coordinate` generic so the numeric literal type of `x` and `y` are known at compile time.  That gives you [this behavior](https://tsplay.dev/WJqGlm), where `move(new Coordinate(1, 0))` will be accepted but `move(new Coordinate(2, 3))` will not.   Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, please [edit] the question to demonstrate failed use cases.

Comment: Yes that almost meets my needs, I would have liked to not use generic type, but without generic `new Coordinate(4, 10)`  would be accepted.

Comment: It's either that or you refactor to something that can be enumerated, like a union of string literals.  [Observe](https://tsplay.dev/wjZ9Yw).  Which solution do you prefer here?

Comment: I prefer an enum like this `const MOVES: { [key in Direction]: Coordinate } = {
  [Direction.Up]: new Coordinate(0, -1),
  [Direction.Right]: new Coordinate(1, 0),
  [Direction.Down]: new Coordinate(0, 1),
  [Direction.Left]: new Coordinate(-1, 0),
};`

Comment: Thanks for your example, it's a good solution, you can use `as const` instead of `Object.freeze`

Comment: Okay, so I could write that up, sure.  I'll do it when I get a chance (might be a number of hours until I have the time)

Answer (score 4):

In order to restrict a TypeScript function input to one of several possible *values*, you would need to be able to identity such values at a the type level.  Such types would need to be "unit" or ["literal" types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) which only admit specific values, and then you could represent your restriction as the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of such literal types.

In TypeScript there are literal types for [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitives).  For example, the string literal type `"hello"` is the type of the string literal `"hello"`, and no other string is assignable to it.  Other such unit types in TypeScript are numeric literal types like `123`, boolean literal types like `true`, and the special types `null` and `undefined`.  There's also [`unique symbol`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol).  And there are literal numeric and string [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) also.

Unfortunately, TypeScript doesn't have the concept of "literal" *object* types.  So you can't really define an `Up` type which is the type of the specific value `const Up = new Cooordinate(0, -1)`.  No matter what you do, you'll be able to come up a distinct other object `AlsoUp` (i.e, `AlsoUp !== Up` at runtime) which is accepted by TypeScript wherever `Up` is.

---

One possible approach is instead to make `Coordinate` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the numeric literal types of the `x` and `y` properties, like this:

```
export class Coordinate<X extends number, Y extends number> {
  constructor(readonly x: X, readonly y: Y) { }
}
```

Then when you construct your directions, you can tell the difference between them at the type level:

```
export const Up = new Coordinate(0, -1); // Coordinate<0, -1>
export const Right = new Coordinate(1, 0); // Coordinate<1, 0>
export const Down = new Coordinate(0, 1); // Coordinate<0, 1>
export const Left = new Coordinate(-1, 0); // Coordinate<-1, 0>
```

And your `Direction` type is the union of these:

```
export type Direction = typeof Up | typeof Right | typeof Down | typeof Left
// type Generic.Direction = Coordinate<0, -1> | Coordinate<1, 0> | 
// Coordinate<0, 1> | Coordinate<-1, 0>

function move(direction: Direction) { }
```

This will prevent you from calling `move()` with coordinates whose `x` and `y` are not the ones you want:

```
move(new Coordinate(4, 10)); // error
```

And it will allow you to call `move()` with one of your approved values:

```
move(Right); // okay
```

But, by necessity, it will *also* allow you to call `move()` with a different object with the same x and y coordinates as the approved direction values:

```
move(new Coordinate(1, 0)); // also okay
```

This might not be a big problem; after all, while the new object isn't *strictly equal* in terms of reference identity, it is "equivalent" in terms of its properties.

---

If you really want to only allow `move()` to be called with one of four specific values, then you can't use object types.  As an alternative, you could use literal types (like, for example, a string enum) as keys which point to your approved objects:

```
enum Direction {
  Up = "U",
  Right = "R",
  Down = "D",
  Left = "L"
}

export const directionMap = {
  [Direction.Up]: new Coordinate(0, -1),
  [Direction.Right]: new Coordinate(1, 0),
  [Direction.Down]: new Coordinate(0, 1),
  [Direction.Left]: new Coordinate(-1, 0)
} as const


function move(dirName: Direction) {
  const direction = directionMap[dirName];
}

move(Direction.Right); // okay
```

Now it's definitely impossible to call `move()` with a different coordinate, because it only accepts the values of the `Direction` string enum.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJKiSwLIDiEwEATgJbx5EkkQAeMA9vQC5J4GEFChIAwjz4ATRqH4QAPAA0kXRcBnjgAVzAAjBgBokATXWdN20vqP0AfK2LsS8HsCj96u+Pz4AFPQQIDIeGACeSJwAXEgqpsGh4VERcWYAlHhIAL5s7HmE+RzcfILunoIAqjBIALykEADuktL0cgoQAQAMpgC0AIwZANzFlrwCQh5eSABKjADmABaCDXQtUrLyIIoBA6bdI2NcE+XTggAiPE3A9Y0bbR07Xb1IQ6MuJadTlUgAMhAAGare6tLadAKDA5HIqfcZlJD8CIwZAXRjBPyMDx3JEoniApA1JAAH0RyIg+LmixWJLJeIJVxutNxFIJAOBYwA9Jy6dRaAxmAA6NEY-hY24NTbtbaKJSvQZOUlSp6y-ZIbqKpBcnnKmXKV4DTW6zpKKHqhxEMaA3TATHYsA8ABuXTkovFcRFEDtwCyuFylrhDudAXWYOlEIALKYBocRkhuep6PQ+GMg115st+HGEzwANYgCKpp1dUPG557aHZnmYKA8JB5gsBkiFfJkaBwRBIACiejAzlcJwRwlE4jLin7rh+Xh8fkCSTCwEi0TivfsiRCC6XaVshgYvv9cJbcNo+iQnu9E9cRIaACIqjfjGMSBmabfZg+n2frhKkDeLh+4RIdkQRvP4bzGI8B1KSYKhmc8xWmO4CEApAAG14PFQUagAXRXZowxVF5+iGR8UPQ9EvQQ4BBRffhcNBMcujVQ5SMnNCMI8YVv3o0tHj1HpowyVjJ3It1OOAnj8MYyFmIyCCkFEKd+ADK0bQvNMAldAA5cAIA9CjvV9T9YMEV1KPFO4OM8VDtN07CPlcSD2A0qyaOpLNhnjHkG0LWFmyIHIgA)

Comment: I prefer the second approach, I think we can just write a simple `enum Direction {Up, Right, Down, Left}`, I don't really see the benefit of using a string enum

Comment: The benefit of using a string enum is that it doesn't have the downside of numeric enums; namely that all `number` values are assignable to them, see [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57334710/2887218).  That means it would accept `move(12345)` which you presumably don't want.  String enums don't let you do that; `move("abcde")` will fail.  Enums are essentially a legacy feature and lots of weird things happen there.

Comment: actually `move("R")` will fails whereas `move(Direction.Right)` works. Weird behavior !

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following, which does have some limitations though:

```
class Coordinate<X extends number, Y extends number> {
  constructor(
    readonly x: X,
    readonly y: Y
  ) {}
}

const Up = new Coordinate(0, -1);
const Right = new Coordinate(1, 0);
const Down = new Coordinate(0, 1);
const Left = new Coordinate(-1, 0);

type Direction =
  typeof Up |
  typeof Right |
  typeof Down |
  typeof Left;

function move(direction: Direction) {
  // ...
}

move(Up);
move(new Coordinate(1, 0));
move(new Coordinate(1, 1)); // Error
```

- You cannot do direct equality comparison between `direction` and one of the constants, because it would compare instances, not the values.
- You now have a type with generics to haul around.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD28BOATAlgOzAFwKYB4ANaXADzwxRgwFcBbAI1yQBpoBNE83S6+ppAD5oAbwBQ0aMHgYI2JDWDZkACgmToSXGBQyQAT2ikAXNEIt1krTr2H9p9uoCUogL5j3Y6bOzQAqgAO0AC80Bi4AO5wiKiYOLgqAAxsALQAjE4A3F4yctAASmgA5gAWvqHhUQjI6Fh4KmlsiVk5PtAAIvARGCFhkdE1cfXJ0BnZ3nkAMrgAZuV9VTG18SrpTS1i2PoBuB1oWkpoMiHqWzvwM-5BAD6n27gXBcVl0LeSZw+Xnd2vd+eX0zm2TEMxoGEOxzo8AAbgl0AdsEcMKZ2vtcBCMC5xJIAPQ4jQEwlEjQAPQA-B4xGIobCVIEWjSEpUBrE6glGtBmgyYUz+tVWSsORkstA8dAAKJIJDIIA)

These limitations could also be mitigated like this:

```
class Coordinate {
  readonly #key = {}
  private constructor(
    readonly x: number,
    readonly y: number
  ) {}

  static Up = new Coordinate(0, -1);
  static Right = new Coordinate(1, 0);
  static Down = new Coordinate(0, 1);
  static Left = new Coordinate(-1, 0);
}

const { Up, Right, Down, Left } = Coordinate;

function move(direction: Coordinate) {
  // ...
}

move(Up);
move({ x: 1, y: 0 }); // Error (Property '#key' is missing...)
move(new Coordinate(1, 0)); // Error (Constructor of class 'Coordinate' is private)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD28BOATAlgOzAFwKbQG8AoaaJXMFeDEAT2gGIBrXegXkIF8ToAHJNADcc+YNQjYkAV2DZkACh6lylanWgAPAFzQMUgLYAjXEgA0SshSo16tHXqMmeASi5EeEnGmDQAqr2gODFwAdzhEVEwReQAGU2gAWgBGZwBuD2wvHwAlNABzAAtsQN1Q8OR0LDx5JPiYtIys6AAReBCMEuCwhAqo6rjoFPTST2xvaAAZXAAzYqCynsiq3HlkuobuIjEMCUI-Xnjcwux41vb4qdnoThLFypF0ommpDFk0amh9eEEV9HI36g6O59XCuYikAD0EOgADo4URNl8fvJ-A0kSsCJodLVoHZoDFrmloFDoABRJBIZDQeQABUpvBM2HoAHJmKxmdA0DB9FyIJg8nCYc4iOj5F1yktojj6kSSeTKUhqQgdpIZHJFfBptBQJAYMzgcsOVy+AJhHhnEA)

Comment: I didn't want to update the `Coordinate` class. This class is used in other parts of the project so I can't make the constructor private

Comment: @OlivierBoissé Fair enough, suspected that this could be the case. The enum approach suggested by jcalz seems to be the best solution then.