# Why does a string literal not match enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm trying to use enums in typescript but they do not seem to typecheck very consistantly. Why can I check that `TestEnum.Foo === 'foo'` without a warning but trying to pass `'foo'` into a function accepting a `TestEnum` causes an error.

```
describe('Test enum functionality', () => {
  enum TestEnum {
    Foo = 'foo',
    Bar = 'bar'
  }

  // I expected this to work as TestEnum.Foo === 'foo'
  test('Can pass string to enum', () => {
    const func = (x: TestEnum) => {}
    // Error: Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TestEnum'
    func('foo');
  });

  // Surprised that this worked after I couldn't pass in a string literal to a function
  test('compiler can verify that this string literal is an Enum option', () => {
    if (TestEnum.Foo === 'foo') {

    }
  });

  // I expect an error here because the compiler should be able to see there is no overlap
  test('compiler can verify that this string literal is not an Enum option', () => {
    // Error: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'TestEnum.Foo' and '"asdf"' have no overlap
    if (TestEnum.Foo === 'asdf') {

    }
  });
});
```

## Update

I removed some unit tests to more clearly show why I'm confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string-valued `enum` is considered to be a *subtype* of the relevant string literals.  In particular, the type of `TestEnum.Foo` is assignable to the string literal `"foo"`, but not vice versa.  This is part of the point of `enum` values; they are meant to be used by name and not by value.  It's an abstraction layer that allows you to change the value of an enum without having to refactor the rest of your code. (This restriction is [not implemented for numeric enums](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26362) for historic reasons and to be usable as bitflags; for a numeric enum, you can pretty much assign any number to or from the enum type.)

The asymmetric assignability between `TestEnum` and `"foo" | "bar"` is why `func("foo")` fails.  The following assignments are safe:

```
const okay: TestEnum = TestEnum.Foo; // okay
const alsoOkay: "foo" | "bar" = TestEnum.Foo; // okay, widening to supertype
```

But this is an error because it's narrowing to a subtype, which is seen as unsafe by the compiler:

```
const bad: TestEnum = "foo"; // error
```

That's similar to how the following is seen as unsafe:

```
const oops: string = Math.random() < 100 ? "hey" : 1; // error
```

Even though at runtime, `oops` will definitely be a "string", the compiler can only verify that it's of the type `string | number` (well, `"hey" | 1`) so it can't allow it.

If you want to do that you'll need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

```
const assertOkay: TestEnum = "foo" as TestEnum; // okay
```

(meaning `func("foo" as TestEnum)` will work for you)

---

As for the comparison with `===`, TypeScript checks (see the `isTypeEqualityComparableTo()` function in the [absolutely humongous `checker.ts` file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/v3.7.2/src/compiler/checker.ts)) that the types of each operand are "related".  Generally two types are related if one of them is a subtype of the other, and unrelated if it is impossible for a value to be of both types at the same time.  (The actual check is considerably more complicated, but those give a good rule of thumb.)  That leads to the following behavior:

```
("foo" === TestEnum.Foo); // okay, TestEnum.Foo is a subtype of "foo"
("bar" === TestEnum.Foo); // error, no overlap between "bar" and TestEnum.Foo
const someTestEnum = Math.random() < 0.5 ? TestEnum.Foo : TestEnum.Bar;
("bar" === someTestEnum); // okay, overlapping types
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsDOAXAouaBvAsAKCnqAYgPZFQC8UA5AGYmUA0O+UAQgIYBO5VARp5TgC+OHAGMiIJFCIBrNgE8AXLAQo03OElSQAdMSIBuKAHpj0ufLESpbADbwiAeQvKARLSKuoAHyiu+HF4Ummq6+kam5goi2OKSiFB8ACbKIdrQFO4krhFmwBwcRBxW8dJEAA7wykgcAJYgAObcALJsiAAWOhxsIElEEAAUAJRQADxQAIwADFNQAPx+7cDyXsoTMXE28PD5iM4Kqarp3FmeUGzwKlpouVGW2DEDp0FkwUdoeiRDt7IK9FehCCfUi1S5sKDwMA8RDycrAaTUPweVw4J4BF5va5hL63fKFDj-ECkIgAN3ytjY5USwEQAHdgKA-Ojzr0AelgSUpA4IMA0uoKK0Ol0en1BiNxlMdABWeZsj76KCHLFA9gcAyo-ycDEQ-q896Qb4mMy-eT-UnkynlepNGFw+AxIA)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is doing exactly what you want it to do. It is telling you that `'asdf' !== 'foo'` and that it never will be so the expression always evaluates to false. This is because both `'asdf'` and `'foo'` are being treated as [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) types. Notice that the following doesn't give you an error:

```
if('foo' === Foo.foo) {

}

if(('asdf' as string) !== Foo.foo) {}
```

In the first case typescript understands that `'foo' === 'foo'` and so no error is thrown. In the second case we are casting `'asdf'` from a `string literal` type to a generic `string` type, and the comparison doesn't error because typescript has been told that `'asdf'` could infact be any string and therefore could potentially be equal to `'foo'`

As for why you can't pass a string literal into a function, I would refer you to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761972/difference-between-string-enums-and-string-literal-types-in-ts), but in essence the answer is, typescript expects you to pass around the reference to the enum, and not the literal itself. That's kind of the point of enums is to not have to know what their literal values are.

Comment: I updated my question to be more clearly focused on the problem. I'm just trying to understand why typescript requries a reference to an enum as it should be able to see there is overlap... which it can some of the time.

Comment: The difference is in using the enum as a value, vs using it as a type. In the if statement you are using `TestEnum.Foo` as a value which evaluates to 'foo' and so the is the string literal 'foo', but in a function you are specifiying x has the type `TestEnum` which tells typescript to only allow the value to be passed by reference.