# js: define options for function arguments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function

I have a question about Javascript/Typescript functions arguments and **clean code**. So I will use a simple example to illustrate my mean.

I created a React component with `view` property as props:

`<Grid view="Horizontal" />`

```
type PropsInterface = {
  view: string
}

const Grid = ( { view }:PropsInterface )=>{
    ...
}
```

`view` can have several options. For example: "Horizontal", "Vertical" etc.

**Question:**
What is the best way to define `view` options so that I don't forget them or that other developers can easily understand?
Is the bottom method good? Are there better ways?

```
type PropsInterface = {
  view: "Horizontal" | "Vertical"
}
```

Comment: If it's more accurate and provides a strongly typed API then why not?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has an [Enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) type -

```
enum ViewDirection {
  Horizontal = "Horizontal",
  Down = "Vertical",
}
```

From [TypeScript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums):

> In modern TypeScript, you may not need an enum when an object with as
> const could suffice:

So you can do:

```
const ViewDirection = {
  Horizontal = "Horizontal",
  Down = "Vertical",
} as const;
```

**VS String Type**

If the values of the strings are subject to change then using a string-enum means only changing 1 string literal, whereas using a string-type means changing them everywhere they're used.

In layman terms you can change `Horizontal = "Horizontal"` to `Horizontal = "H"` without the need to change it everywhere when using a string enum.

More in depth here:

[Difference between string enums and string literal types in TS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761972/difference-between-string-enums-and-string-literal-types-in-ts)