# defining multiple variables with a condition in python

Tags: python

i'm making a code where in one part I need to access to data inside a DataFrame. The main problem is that the columns in dataframe may change depending on file accessed. So i've thinked that I could define aux var for the keys to access it. My main problem now is that the code seems to work but the solusion looks pretty ugly.

```
if isAirData:
        LOGlat  = 'latitude'
        LOGlon  = 'longitude'
        LOGalt  = 'height_above_takeoff(feet)'
        LOGtime = 'datetime(utc)'
        LOGhead = 'compass_heading(degrees)'
        LOGpitch= 'gimbal_pitch(degrees)'#pitch(degrees)'
        LOGroll = 'roll(degrees)'
        LOGvid  = 'isVideo'
else:
        LOGlat  = 'OSD.latitude'
        LOGlon  = 'OSD.longitude'
        LOGalt  = 'OSD.height[ft]'
        LOGtime = 'CUSTOM.updateTime[local]'
        LOGhead = 'OSD.yaw'
        LOGpitch= 'OSD.pitch'
        LOGroll = 'OSD.roll'
        LOGvid  = 'CAMERA.isVideo'
```

these are my keys of interest. In the different files column number and names changes. So I was wondering which is the best way to work with this?

Comment: IMO your code isn't that ugly. If you wanted to use something else, then you could always use the [ternary operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ternary-operator-in-python)

Comment: I don't see anything ugly with your code but, depending on how are those variables used, you might improve the maintenance effort by using a dictionary or a list of tuples but, as I said, it depends on how likable is that list of variables to change or whether you can optimize the code by traversing over them.

Answer (score 1):

First I would create a json file for each file type that you may access, something like this:

```
{
   'LOGlat': 'latitude',
   'LOGlon': 'longitude',
   ...
}
```

Then I would access the relevant file, saving the keys for the DataFrame in a dictionary.
My code would look something like this:

```
import json

def read_file(path):
    file = open(path)
    data = file.read()
    file.close()
    return data

isAirData = True
keys = {}

if isAirData:
    data = read_file('isAir.json')
    keys = json.loads(data)
else:
    data = read_file('isNotAir.json')
    keys = json.loads(data)
```

Now all you need to do to access a column name is:

```
DataFrame[keys['key_name']]
```

I know that this solution will slow down your code, but if all you want is pretty-looking code, this works fine

Hope you find this useful

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class container. I'd suggest inheriting from [`StrEnum`](https://pypi.org/project/StrEnum/), though it can be superfluous:

```
from strenum import StrEnum

class AirData(StrEnum):
        LOGlat  = 'latitude'
        LOGlon  = 'longitude'
        LOGalt  = 'height_above_takeoff(feet)'
        LOGtime = 'datetime(utc)'
        LOGhead = 'compass_heading(degrees)'
        LOGpitch= 'gimbal_pitch(degrees)'#pitch(degrees)'
        LOGroll = 'roll(degrees)'
        LOGvid  = 'isVideo'

class NotAirData(StrEnum):
        LOGlat  = 'OSD.latitude'
        LOGlon  = 'OSD.longitude'
        LOGalt  = 'OSD.height[ft]'
        LOGtime = 'CUSTOM.updateTime[local]'
        LOGhead = 'OSD.yaw'
        LOGpitch= 'OSD.pitch'
        LOGroll = 'OSD.roll'
        LOGvid  = 'CAMERA.isVideo'
```

So you can use a single definition as

```
mylabels = AirData if isAirData else NotAirData
do_something(mylabels.LOGlat)
```

Pros:

- The item is treated as a string type whenever needed
- You don't need external resource files: you can just import the module containing the two defined classes.

Comment: It's a good solution I think, here a question why to make the class inherit from `StrEnum` ? wich are the pros of this?

Comment: Just the advantages coming from an enumerator. But I agree with you, it can be superfluous

Comment: sorry my ignorance, but wich are this adventages? If don't mind you to explain if not i will go to read.

Comment: Easy iteration through the elements, just to mention one for this case. Check this answer for more advs https://stackoverflow.com/a/37601645/5321862

Comment: For example: `headers=[header for header in AirData]` gives you a headers list for your Qt table straight away