# Can an Enum be used as a dispatch table?

Tags: python, enums

The first part of [this blog post](http://lukasz.langa.pl/8/single-dispatch-generic-functions/) does a nice job of summarizing the general use case for a dispatch table, but I can't help wondering if it could be even more succinct and elegant using `Enum`s instead...

Of course, the big hurdle in using an `Enum` is that functions are automatically ignored as potential members.

So, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: *Yes*<sup>1</sup>.

I will show a solution using [the `aenum`<sup>2</sup> library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) -- while it is possible to do most of this with the stdlib version it would require writing extra plumbing that already exists in `aenum`.

First, the base class:

```
from aenum import Enum, enum

class CallableEnum(Enum):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._impl = args[0]
        if member._impl.__doc__ is not None:
            member._value_ = member._impl.__doc__
        else:
            member._value_ = repr(member._impl)
        return member

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
        return self._impl(*args, **kwds)
```

and an example dispatch `Enum`:

```
class TestEnum(CallableEnum):

    @enum
    def hello(text):
        "a pleasant greeting"
        print('hello,', text)

    @enum
    def goodbye(text):
        print('goodbye,', text)
```

and in use:

```
>>> list(TestEnum)
[
  <TestEnum.hello: 'a pleasant greeting'>,
  <TestEnum.goodbye: '<function goodbye at 0xb7264844>'>,
]

>>> print(TestEnum.hello)
TestEnum.hello

>>> TestEnum['hello']('how are you?')
'hello, how are you?'

>>> TestEnum['goodbye']('see you soon!')
'goodbye, see you soon!'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22594360/208880) for the standard `Enum` usage.

<sup>2</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: unfortunately this is not picklable on OSX at least

Comment: @amohr: It seems to work on Ubuntu.  Can you make a new question with the sample code you used and the errors/exceptions raised?

Comment: indeed, it was working in our docker containers but not locally.  The issue is that the value on OSX ends up being the \__repr__ of the value, which is a garbage string.

Answer (score 0):

So first I used the above implementation, but then realized it wasn't pickling correctly on OSX, so now I'm using this:

```py
    def _utcnow_plus_delta(delta: timedelta, utcnow_attr: tOptional[str] = None, delta_attr: tOptional[str] = None):
        dt = datetime.utcnow()
        if utcnow_attr:
            dt = getattr(dt, utcnow_attr)
            if callable(dt):
                dt = dt()

        dt += delta

        if delta_attr:
            delta_val = getattr(dt, delta_attr)
            return delta_val() if callable(delta_val) else delta_val

        return dt


    @unique
    class DynamicValue(Enum):
        DATE_TODAY_PLUS_ONE_DAY = partial(_utcnow_plus_delta, timedelta(days=1), 'date')
        DATE_TODAY_PLUS_TWO_YEARS = partial(_utcnow_plus_delta, timedelta(weeks=52 * 2), 'date')
        DATE_TODAY_PLUS_FIVE_YEARS = partial(_utcnow_plus_delta, timedelta(weeks=52 * 5), 'date')
        DATE_TODAY_PLUS_TEN_YEARS = partial(_utcnow_plus_delta, timedelta(weeks=52 * 10), 'date')
        YEAR_TODAY_PLUS_FIVE_YEARS = partial(_utcnow_plus_delta, timedelta(weeks=52 * 5), 'date', delta_attr='year')
        TIMESTAMP_NOW_PLUS_FIVE_YEARS = partial(_utcnow_plus_delta, timedelta(weeks=52 * 5), delta_attr='timestamp')

        def __reduce_ex__(self, proto):
            assert proto >= 4
            return self.__class__.__qualname__ + '.' + self._name_
```

I think the above CallableEnum can be fixed by adding an appropriate reduce_ex method to ensure it gets re-created from the global value and not the repr. It's a little annoying in that you have to do enum.value() but no biggie I think