# Python Enum shows weird behavior when using same dictionary for member values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, enums

I don't understand why this Enum doesn't have all the members I defined, when I assign a dict as each member's value:

```
from enum import Enum

class Token(Enum):
    facebook = {
    'access_period': 0,
    'plan_name': ''}

    instagram = {
    'access_period': 0,
    'plan_name': ''}

    twitter = {
    'access_period': 0,
    'plan_name': ''}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(Token))
```

The output is:

```
[<Token.twitter: {'plan_name': '', 'access_period': 0}>]
```

… but I expected something like:

```
[<Token.facebook:  {'plan_name': '', 'access_period': 0}>,
 <Token.instagram: {'plan_name': '', 'access_period': 0}>,
 <Token.twitter:   {'plan_name': '', 'access_period': 0}>]
```

Why aren't all the members shown?

Comment: It's because they all have the same value. That's not how enums are supposed to work.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has received a down-vote. The writing could be improved -- yes. However the question shows a not necessarily intuitive behavior of the Enum module.

Comment: @Fartash you might want to double-check your spelling and rewrite the question title.

Comment: @MichaelHoff:  Agreed.  The question itself is well worded, shows the code to reproduce the problem, and describes the desired outcome.  I wish all questions were this good!

Comment: Any reason you need Enum?

Comment: This use case is likely a really bad fit for an `Enum`. Have you considered a plain `dict` instead? If you think you must use an `Enum` at all costs, please explain why.

Answer (score 5):

[Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) enforces unique values for the members. Member definitions with the same value as other definitions will be treated as aliases.

Demonstration:

```
Token.__members__
# OrderedDict([('twitter',
#               <Token.twitter: {'plan_name': '', 'access_period': 0}>),
#              ('facebook',
#               <Token.twitter: {'plan_name': '', 'access_period': 0}>),
#              ('instagram',
#               <Token.twitter: {'plan_name': '', 'access_period': 0}>)])

assert Token.instagram == Token.twitter
```

The defined **names** do all exist, however they are all mapped to the same member.

Have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/enum.py#L213) if you are interested:

```
# [...]
# If another member with the same value was already defined, the
# new member becomes an alias to the existing one.
for name, canonical_member in enum_class._member_map_.items():
    if canonical_member._value_ == enum_member._value_:
        enum_member = canonical_member
        break
else:
    # Aliases don't appear in member names (only in __members__).
    enum_class._member_names_.append(member_name)
# performance boost for any member that would not shadow
# a DynamicClassAttribute
if member_name not in base_attributes:
    setattr(enum_class, member_name, enum_member)
# now add to _member_map_
enum_class._member_map_[member_name] = enum_member
try:
    # This may fail if value is not hashable. We can't add the value
    # to the map, and by-value lookups for this value will be
    # linear.
    enum_class._value2member_map_[value] = enum_member
except TypeError:
    pass
# [...]
```

---

Further, it seems to me that you want to exploit the Enum class to modify the value (the dictionary) during run-time. This is strongly discouraged and also very unintuitive for other people reading/using your code. An enum is expected to be made of constants.

Comment: The line "The members do exist" could be worded more clearly, maybe "The different names exist, but they all map to the same member" ?

Comment: Fair point. I was not too sure about the correct terminology. As `len(Token.__members__) == 3` one could understand that there are three "members". Answer updated.

Comment: Hah, I just had to make the same change to my answer! :/

Answer (score 4):

As [@MichaelHoff noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43523125/208880), the behavior of `Enum` is to consider names with the same values to be aliases<sup>1</sup>.

You can get around this by using the [`Advanced Enum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>2</sup> library:

```
from aenum import Enum, NoAlias

class Token(Enum):
    _settings_ = NoAlias
    facebook = {
        'access_period': 0,
        'plan_name': '',
        }

    instagram = {
        'access_period': 0,
        'plan_name': '',
        }

    twitter = {
        'access_period': 0,
        'plan_name': '',
        }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print list(Token)
```

Output is now:

```
[
  <Token.twitter: {'plan_name': '', 'access_period': 0}>,
  <Token.facebook: {'plan_name': '', 'access_period': 0}>,
  <Token.instagram: {'plan_name': '', 'access_period': 0}>,
  ]
```

To reinforce what Michael said:  `Enum` members are meant to be constants -- you shouldn't use non-constant values unless you really know what you are doing.

---

A better example of using `NoAlias`:

```
class CardNumber(Enum):

    _order_ = 'EIGHT NINE TEN JACK QUEEN KING ACE'  # only needed for Python 2.x
    _settings_ = NoAlias

    EIGHT    = 8
    NINE     = 9
    TEN      = 10
    JACK     = 10
    QUEEN    = 10
    KING     = 10
    ACE      = 11
```

---

<sup>1</sup> See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22594360/208880) for the standard `Enum` usage.

<sup>2</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum) library.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the `NoAlias` behavior for the stdlib?

Comment: @MichaelHoff: Not easily, no.  It falls into the category of "you can if you really want to, but nobody is going to enjoy reading that code!"  ;)

Comment: How dislikable is `def __init__(self, *args): self._value_ = (self.name,) + args`? ;)

Comment: @MichaelHoff: That will not work with mixin types, such as `int`, and would also make by-value lookups fail (instead of `CardNumber(8)` it would be `CardNumber(('EIGHT', 8))`.

Comment: Surprisingly it does work* with `IntEnum` but yes, the lookup via constructor will fail. (*at least the use cases I tested have been just fine)

Comment: @MichaelHoff, Huh, interesting.  Guess I should have tested that statement first!  But hey, I was right on the lookup!  :)  Plus it's still early here... ;)