# How to add a method to an enum?

Tags: python, enums

I would like to add a method to my enum.

```
class Kerneltype(Enum):
    tube = 0
    subspace_KDE = 1
    deltashift = 2
    dist_sens_via_mass_1 = 3

    def aslist(self):
        return [self.tube, self.subspace_KDE, self.deltashift, self.dist_sens_via_mass_1]

    def fromint(self, int):
        return self.aslist()[int]
```

does not work. Instead of

```
Kerneltype.aslist()
```

I currently have to do

```
[kt[1] for kt in ob.Kerneltype.__members__.items()]
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a very _vague_ problem description. Please be more specific and provide us with any error messages you're getting.

Comment: Note, your `aslist` method does not do anything that `list(Kerneltype)` would not give you automatically.

Comment: The docs can be very helpful here; you don't need a method to [iterate over your enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#iteration) and you can access it by integer index by [calling it like a function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#programmatic-access-to-enumeration-members-and-their-attributes).

Comment: @Ben The function call actually expects a value not index.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary `Kerneltype.fromi(1) is Kerneltype(1)` is a `True` epxpression- just to make sure, I implemented this with those @classmethod  decorators from your answer and checked.

Comment: @Ben That's working because the items in the Enum are also similar to indices, change `subspace_KDE` to say 5 and then try again.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Okay I see what you mean. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 19):

You created an instance method, so `aslist` only exists on instances of `Kerneltype` (i.e. the enum members themselves). You need [a classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) instead:

```
@classmethod
def aslist(cls):
    return [cls.tube, cls.subspace_KDE, cls.deltashift, cls.dist_sens_via_mass_1]
```

```
>>> Kerneltype.aslist()
[<Kerneltype.tube: 0>, <Kerneltype.subspace_KDE: 1>, <Kerneltype.deltashift: 2>, <Kerneltype.dist_sens_via_mass_1: 3>]
```

Comment: Why @classmethod and not @staticmethod?

Comment: @zzz777 See [this question for the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/136097/216074). Static methods don’t have access to the class type, and as such its class properties.

Comment: Sorry could not decipher much from the discussion. I am only using classes because I want to access/manipulate data encapsulated in a class (my past is in c++). The discussion was centered around printing class names in various ways. There are static variables in a class and class variables, is the only big difference is that class variables/methods could be modified by derived classes? It will be really nice if you can shed some light.

Comment: @zzz777 Python doesn’t have “static variables” in the sense of other languages. The members in OP’s example, e.g. `tube` and `deltashift`, are [class variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) that are stored on the class/type instead of an instance. If you want to access those, you will need to have a reference to the type. That reference is the `cls` that is passed to `@classmethod` methods but not `@staticmethod` methods.

Comment: Sorry it seems like some sort of misunderstanding I am using static variables in classes in python3 right now and it seems working well. Sorry again I will try to formulate my question differently.

Answer (score 6):

You should be defining your methods with the [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) decorator as you are calling them from the class and not the Enum member.

```
@classmethod
def aslist(cls):
    return [cls.tube, cls.subspace_KDE, cls.deltashift, cls.dist_sens_via_mass_1]

@classmethod
def fromint(cls, int):
    return cls.aslist()[int]
```

---

As others have mentioned in comments, your `aslist()` method is not required and you can directly use [`list()` on it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#iteration) and it by default preserves the order of definition. Only difference is that it doesn't return the aliases.

```
>>> list(Kerneltype)
[<Kerneltype.tube: 0>, <Kerneltype.subspace_KDE: 1>, <Kerneltype.deltashift: 2>, <Kerneltype.dist_sens_via_mass_1: 3>]
```

Comment: Every member is an instance of the Enum class, and instance methods do make sense (just not in this example).

Comment: Fair enough, here's an example:  [Python Enum, when and where to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22594360/208880)

Comment: @EthanFurman Thanks, have updated my answer to remove the bit related to instantiation.

Comment: I did a little more rewording -- hopefully you like it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You missed the [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod) decorator:

```
@classmethod
def aslist(self):
    return [self.tube, self.subspace_KDE, self.deltashift, self.dist_sens_via_mass_1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with what you do is trying to access enum values via `self` whereas you should access them as you would normally via the enum.

```py
from enum import Enum

class V(Enum):
    V1 = (1, 2)
    V2 = (2, 3)
    def getKey(v: float):
        return [k for k in list(V) if v > k.value[0] and v < k.value[1]]

V.getKey(1.1) #  [<V.V1: (1, 2)>]
V.getKey(1.1)[0].value # (1, 2)
```