# Python - Replace regular expression match with a matching pair value

Tags: python, regex, enumeration

Let's say I have a list of aliases tied to 5 digit codes available at runtime:

```
aliasPairs = [(12345,'bob'),(23456,'jon'),(34567,'jack'),(45678,'jill'),(89012,'steph')]
```

I want to find a terse way to express: replace the id in the line with the matching alias, e.g. :

```
line = "hey there 12345!"
line = re.sub('\d{5}', value in the aliasPairs which matches the ID, line)
print line
```

Should output:

```
hey there bob!
```

How do Python pros write enumerative expressions in a terse manner?

Thanks and cheers!

Comment: So each five digit code corresponds to one alias? Consider using a dictionary.

Comment: @Kevin that would also do, however an extensible data structure doesn't really matter too much because I will only have a max of about 10-15 aliases hard coded. I am more wondering how to do lambdas and the like in Python.

Comment: Python doesn't have a built-in function for lookups in an association list, which is why you want a dictionary. `dict(aliasPairs)` will build the dictionary for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a dictionary when you have a one-to-one mapping of two categories of data, such as five digit codes and aliases. Then it's easy to access any particular alias, given its code:

```
import re

aliases = {
    "12345":"bob",
    "23456":"jon",
    "34567":"jack",
    "45678":"jill",
    "89012":"steph"
}

line = "hey there 12345!"
line = re.sub('\d{5}', lambda v: aliases[v.group()], line)
print(line)
```

Result:

```
hey there bob!
```

Comment: Awesome, I absolutely love the lambda call.

Answer (score 1):

If you will be using these aliases directly in your code (not just referenced from data structures) then an `Enum` is a good way to go<sup>1</sup>:

```
from enum import Enum

class Alias(Enum):
    bob = 12345
    jon = 23456
    jack = 34567
    jill = 45678
    steph = 89012
```

Then using `re` would look like:

```
line = "hey there 12345!"
line = re.sub('\d{5}', lambda v: Alias(int(v.group()).name, line)
```

You could also add that behavior directly to the `Alias` `Enum` with a method:

```
    @classmethod
    def sub(cls, line):
        return re.sub('\d{5}', lambda v: cls(int(v.group())).name, line)
```

and in use:

```
Alias.sub("hey there 12345!")
```

Of course, `"bob"` should probably be capitalized, but who wants `Alias.Bob` all over their code?  Best to have the substitution text be separate from the Enum member name, a job more easily accomplished with [`aenum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>2</sup>:

```
from aenum import Enum
import re

class Alias(Enum):
    _init_ = 'value text'
    bob = 12345, 'Bob'
    jon = 23456, 'Jon'
    jack = 34567, 'Jack'
    jill = 45678, 'Jill'
    steph = 89012, 'Steph'
    @classmethod
    def sub(cls, line):
        return re.sub('\d{5}', lambda v: cls(int(v.group())).text, line)

Alias.sub('hey there 34567!')
```

---

<sup>1</sup> See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22594360/208880) for the standard `Enum` usage.

<sup>2</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: This is a really cool use of the of Enums. Question: the Alias.sub call looks kind of like a static access call to the class Alias, does the _init_ get called the first time I call the Alias.sub method or upon invocation with every call to the 'class'?

Comment: @Rice:  In `Enum` classes all the `Enum` members (aka class instances) are created when the class itself is created; both `__new__` and `__init__` are invoked at that time.   Any future operations that return an `Enum` member are returning one of the already created members.