# Is there a way to instantiating a class directly from an Enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, enums, instance

I recently found out you can use enums in Python, but I'm not happy with how my code is working and I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to implement it.

```py
from enum import Enum

class Hex:
    def __init__(self, hex_code: str):
        self.code = hex_code

class Rgb:
    def __init__(self, R: int, G: int, B: int):
        self.r = R
        self.g = G
        self.b = B

class Color(Enum):
    HEX = Hex
    RGB = Rgb

def main():
    hex_color = Color.HEX.value('#00FF00')
    rgb_color = Color.RGB.value(255, 255, 255)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In this example I have to instantiate by calling the `.value()` enum method. but when you instantiate a class normally, all you do is `Class(value)`. Would it be possible to implement something similar to enum variants that holds a class?
For example:

```py
Color.HEX('#00FF00')
# Instead of:
Color.HEX.value('#00FF00')
```

Comment: no, there isn't without fundamentally changing how `enum` works. What is your use-case for enum here? why not just use the classes directly? In any case, `value` isn't a method, it is simply the attribute on the enum object which holds the *value* you gave to that enum member.

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure the OP is trying to dynamically generate a class.

Comment: @chepner but to me it seems like the issue is that the OP wants to be able to call `Color.HEX()` to instantiate an instance, rather than `Color.HEX.value()`. Honestly, to do what you're trying to do i would just use the class definition statement and simply `del` the names, if that was bothering me. Of course, I simply think that this isn't a use-case for `enum`

Comment: Actually, I forgot that since a `class` statement is just a fancy assignment statement, you can just nest the definitions of `Hex` and `Rgb` directly in `Color`, so that eliminates the need for the `type` hackery. True, it doesn't eliminate the issue of having to use `value` to get back the actual type instance.

Comment: I ran your code, unfortunately IDLE's subprocess did not make connection

Comment: I mostly want to learn more in depth how i can use enums. cause in other languages I've been programming in, they have been very useful. 

That being said. my main goal with trying this approach were to make an easy API for grouping types together so i can access them with a deterministic path. while being able to assign shared behavior.
`Color.HEX('#00ff00')`
Instead of the following and not knowing what it belongs to.
`Hex('#00ff00')`

But after closer inspection i agree with the comments in here. that it makes more sense to use modules for pathing.

Answer (score 3):

`HEX` and `RGB` are not classes; they are *instances* of `Color`. (`enum` uses a metaclass that abuses the `class` statement quite a bit.) You use the `value` attribute of those instances to get the value you "assigned" to those names.

In order to make `Color.HEX('#00ff00')` return an instance of the class `Hex`, you need to define `Color.__call__`. (As an aside, note that you can simply define the two classes inside the `class` statement that defines `Color`, rather than defining them externally. A `class` statement is just a fancy assignment statement at heart.)

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    class HEX:
        def __init__(self, hex_code: str):
            self.code = hex_code

    class RGB:
        def __init__(self, R: int, G: int, B: int):
            self.r = R
            self.g = G
            self.b = B

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.value(*args)
```

Then

```
>>> Color.HEX('#00ff00')
<__main__.Color.HEX object at 0x108740f28>
```

---

There's no inherited value of `__call__` being overriden, so there's no immediate need to use anything like `super().__call__(*args)` in its definition. That might change if you think you'll need to support multiple inheritance, but given the use of a custom metaclass by `Enum`, I'm going to declare handling that beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: This is cool, but then why bring `Enum` into the picture at all?  Just use `Color(object)` and give it class attributes?

Comment: That's a question you could ask about just about *any* use of `Enum`.

Comment: There are good use-cases for using `Enum` -- the OP's is not one of them.

Comment: I'm not a fan of nesting the classes inside. cause it makes them unavailable outside. doing this approach i would rather just have the enum point at the outer class definitions. not having them defined inside.

Comment: You weren't using them outside the class in the first place; the whole point of the question was how to write `Color.HEX(...)` instead of `Hex(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing in your question that requires, or is benefited by, the use of `Enum`.

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22594360/208880) for guidelines on using `Enum`.

`Enum` does offer easy membership testing, so you could do:

```
hex_value is rgb_value
```

or

```
hex_value in Color
```

Using the `aenum`<sup>1</sup> library, your code would look like this:

```
from aenum import Enum, extend_enum

class Color(Enum):
    #
    def __new__(cls, value):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = value
        member.hex = hex(value)[2:]
        r, value = divmod(value, 1 << 16)
        g, value = divmod(value, 1 << 8)
        b = value
        member.red = r
        member.green = g
        member.blue = b
        member.rgb = r, g, b
        return member
    #
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        # r, g, b = value
        name = 'rgb:%r' % (value, )
        # name = 'rgb:%r' % ((r << 16) + (g << 8) + b, )
        extend_enum(cls, name, value)
        return cls[name]
    #
    @classmethod
    def from_hex(cls, value):
        # on leading #
        red = int(value[:2], 16)
        green = int(value[2:4], 16)
        blue = int(value[4:], 16)
        value = (red << 16) + (green << 8) + blue
        return cls(value)
    #
    @classmethod
    def from_rgb(cls, red, green, blue):
        value = (red << 16) + (green << 8) + blue
        return cls(value)
    #
    RED = 255 << 16
    GREEN = 255 << 8
    BLUE = 255
```

and in use:

```
>>> list(Color)
[<Color.RED: 16711680>, <Color.GREEN: 65280>, <Color.BLUE: 255>]

>>> Color.from_rgb(255, 0, 0)
<Color.RED: 16711680>

>>> Color.from_hex('00FF00')
<Color.GREEN: 65280>

>>> Color.from_hex('15A97F')
<Color.rgb:1419647: 1419647>

>>> Color.from_rgb(21, 169, 127)
<Color.rgb:1419647: 1419647>

>>> Color.from_hex('15A97F') is Color.from_rgb(21, 169, 127)
True
```

You can, of course, change the details of the `repr()`, the stored attributes (`red`, `green`, `blue`, `hex`, `rgb`, etc).

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: I came to the realization that my way of using the Enum here isn't very pythonic. i'm used to languages that doesn't have inheritance. were grouping types in an Enum is very useful. but in this case it doesn't offer any benefits apart from the pathing. which can be achived by nesting modules in folders using normal inheritance.