# How do I properly document python enum elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, documentation

I understand that I can add a Python docstring to an enum type as I would any other class. But how do I add documentation to an element of that type?

As far as I can see there are three possibilities:

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    """
    This is my enum type.
    """

    """
    Variant 1
    """
    a = 0,  
    b = 1, # variant 2
    c = 2, """ variant 3 """
```

But none of them really work consistently.
If I call `print(inspect.getdoc(MyEnum.a))` in any of the variants, the docstring of the `MyEnum` type is returned ('This is my enum type'). Pycharm can show variant 3 in its Quick Documentation preview, but includes the quotes and longer comments that exceed the column wrap will not be shown correctly.

Is there a preferred way or convention on how to document Python enum elements?

Comment: You should be aware that tripe-quoted strings are still strings, and the commas after your values are causing them to be evaluated as tuples.  Your `MyEnum.a` has value `(0,)`, and `MyEnum.c` has value `(2, ' variant 3 ')`!

Comment: Wow thank you Patrick, I hadn't even thought of that, although it's very obvious now that you pointed it out.

Comment: What `inspect.getdoc()` is returning **is** the docstring of your `MyEnum` class, and is therefore correct due to how they are handled in Python. How you document the values is strictly how you want to do it—so there's no "proper" way to do it.

Comment: But I don't want the docstring of the type, I want that of the element.

Comment: Why not name the enum variables themselves in a self-documenting way e.g. replacing `a` with `VARIANT_A`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If the values themselves are not important, see [How do I put docstrings on Enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19330460/208880).  If the values are important you can either customize that answer or use the `aenum`<sup>1</sup> library:

```
from aenum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
    _init_ = 'value __doc__'
    a = 0, 'docstring for a'
    b = 1, 'another for b'
    c = 2, 'and one for c as well'
```

which results in:

```
>>> MyEnum.b.value
1
>>> MyEnum.b.__doc__
'another for b'
```

However, I do not know which, if any, IDEs support using Enum member doc strings.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: Thank you Ethan! And thanks for marking the duplicate. Hadn't found the question and it definitely didn't show up in the suggestions when I formulated the question.

Comment: @thrau:  No worries, happy to help.

Comment: How would this work if I'm already defining a custom __init__ function?

Comment: Put `doc=None` as the last parameter of your `__init__`, then include a doc as the last piece of each member declaration.  The link in the answer has an example.

Comment: As of 2022 there is a """ way which is intellisense-prefered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330460/how-do-i-put-docstrings-on-enums